# UI Testing iOS, Selecting Secure Text Entry textField

Tags: ios, uitextfield, xcode-ui-testing

I have password and password conf textFields that I have applied the "Secure Text Entry", to mask the password. However, when I run the UI tests, those fields can not be found getting

> UI Testing Failure - No matches found for "password" TextField

I'm attempting to select the fields like so:

```
let passwordTextField = app.textFields["password"]
```

but then it fails when I try to tap:

```
passwordTextField.tap()
```

Any ideas on how I can access the field?

Comment: What's the failure message?

Comment: The failure specifically is "UI Testing Failure - No matches found for "password" TextField". But when I unselect "Secure Text Entry" it finds it no problem

Comment: Can you open the Accessibility Inspector and see what the text field's identifier is? It might not be password when it becomes a sure entry field.

Comment: Also, can you try using `secureTextFields` instead of `textFields`?

Comment: Just rechecked, the Accessibility Inspector and the identifier is "password".

Answer (score 47, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, when accessing a secure text field use the `secureTextFields` selector.

```
let passwordTextField = app.secureTextFields["password"]
passwordTextField.tap()
passwordTextField.typeText("my secure password")
```

Comment: Wow. I've looked at several articles regarding this UI Testing and this is the first time I've heard of the `secureTextFields` selector. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Also if you need to type to secureTextField

If menu I/O Hardware Keyboard is ON typeText not working for secureTextField.

[image]

Use below to type to secure field

```
        password.tap()

        app.keys["t"].tap()
        app.keys["e"].tap()
        app.keys["s"].tap()
        app.keys["t"].tap()
```

Answer (score 0):

Joe's answer is good, but it was insufficient for my use case. I had to find *all* text fields by index, no matter if it's a normal text field or a secure text field. I couldn't find any information on the web about this.

That's what I came up with:

```swift
// elementType must be specified as integer
//
// See:
//  * https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuielementtype/xcuielementtypetextfield
//  * https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuielementtype/xcuielementtypesecuretextfield
let textFieldPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "elementType == 49")
let secureTextFieldPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "elementType == 50")
let predicate = NSCompoundPredicate(
    orPredicateWithSubpredicates: [
        textFieldPredicate,
        secureTextFieldPredicate
    ]
)

let textFields = app.descendants(matching: .any).matching(predicate)
let textField = textFields.firstMatch
textField.tap()
textField.typeText('yeah boi')
```